# TFS 2010 Rename items in ALLOWEDVALUES and update all existing workitems

Tags: tfs

I need to change one of the item in ALLOWEDVALUES, and preferably to update all existing workitem and possibly all history as well, is there any built in TFS 2010 command or function to do this? If not, can I update the table directly, after applying the new ALLOWEDVALUES?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a query and open it in excel. This will allow you to easily bulk edit all of the old values to the new ones. If you create a query with the right columns you can right click on it in visual studio and open in excel. The other way round you can open excel and use the Team tab to open the query. The you can update all if the work items and save in one go.

if you plan on keeping some of the old values around you should also add  so that folks can still save without changing the value.

Comment: Will this update the data in TFS directly? What about historical ones?